# How can I increment the value of only one index in the array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, mysqli

```
$vaccinesArr=array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0");    
for($i = 0; $i < 11 ; $i++){
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          if ($row['vaccID']== $i){
               $vaccineArr[$i]++;                 
          }               
       }
    }
```

This is the part of my code, I need to increment according to this condition but I keep on getting syntax error, I searched but all the results I find are using foreach and incrementing all the indexes of the array while here I want to increment only one specific index. Can anyone help?

Comment: what syntax error you are getting?

Comment: You don't need a for loop. For what?! Just fetch the data and use `$row["vaccID"]` as key. Any expression is valid as key: `$array[(expression)]` The expression will just evaluate to the key. So in your example: `$vaccineArr[$row["vaccID"]]`

Comment: You have `$vaccinesArr` in you first line, but `$vaccineArr` inside the `if`. Also if you increment the values and __treat them as ints__, don't initialize them as strings.

Comment: Also if you get an error always include it in your question! I make the assumption here based on your code that you get an error about fetching data from a non-object. But I could also be wrong and that is why you should include it!

Comment: the for loop is because I am making a counter for how many times each index of the array is repeated in the fetched data. I am not quite catching on the expression part you are talking about, is there another method than the one I am trying to use? - Rizier123

Comment: The error was for the string part and that the array was not initialised to start with, now it is fixed!

Comment: When the `while` loop ends, there won't be any more rows to fetch from the query. So when the `for()` loop goes to the next iteration, the `while` loop won't do anything.

Comment: @n.am 1) Just saw `vaccinesArr` != `vaccineArr` typo 2) `$row['vaccID']` is the index of your array element which you want to increment, so use it as key.

Comment: so if I store the values of the query result in an array and use it for the comparision, I guess that will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will only work on the first iteration of the `for` loop, because when the inner `while` loop finishes there won't be any more rows to fetch from the query. You could rewind the query, but a better way to do it would be without the `for` loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $vaccinesArr[$row['vaccID']]++;
}
```

Also, if the elements of `$vaccinesArr` are supposed to be numbers, you shouldn't put them in quotes. PHP will convert the strings to numbers when you use `++`, but why be confusing?

```
$vaccinesArr = array(0, 0, 0, ....);
```

Comment: Each time you call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` it fetches the next row from the result set. Unless you rewind back to the beginning, any rows fetched previously will not be fetched again. If you want to process the results multiple times, the best way is to use one loop to to put them all in an array (or use `mysqli_fetch_all()`) and then use `foreach()` every time you want to process the data.

Comment: can't I assign my query result to two variables and use each variable separately when fetching? Like this?

$result = Modulator::getDb()->query($getDoctorReport);
$result1 = Modulator::getDb()->query($getDoctorReport);

Comment: That performs the query twice, which is unnecessary overhead on the database. Much simpler to do the query once, collect all the rows into an array, and then use that multiple times.